# How can ng-options work wtihout a controller?

Tags: angularjs, dropdown, ng-options

I have an array of strings `['One', 'Two', 'Three']` that I'd like to use as `<option>` tags in my Angular component. I don't want to use a controller. I just want to use ng-options. How does this work?

In the component I have variable declarations:

```
array: String[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
selectedString: String = 'Two';
```

And in the component's HTML file I have:

```
<div [ngClass]="setClasses()">
    <select id="testCodeSelect" name="testCodeSelect" ng-model="selectedCode">
        <option *ngFor="let code of codes" value="code.alphabetic">{{ code.alphabetic }}</option>
    </select>
    <select id="codeSelect" name="codeSelect" ng-model="selectedString" ng-options="test as test in array"></select>
</div>
```

Things that don't work:

```
<select id="codeSelect" name="codeSelect" ng-model="selectedString" ng-options="test for test in array"></select>
<select id="codeSelect" name="codeSelect" ng-model="selectedString" ng-options="test as test for test in array"></select>
<select id="codeSelect" name="codeSelect" ng-model="selectedString" ng-options="item for item in ['One', 'Two', 'Three']"></select>
```

Comment: share the code you have tried.

Comment: I've updated the post with more information. There are only two files, a TS file and HTML file, both for the component.

Comment: You are mixing AngularJS and Angular syntax.  `*ngFor`, `[ngClass]` is Angular, `ng-for`, `{{}}` is AngularJS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you asked for something like -
`

```
<select ng-init="colors = [{ name:'1', shade: '1s' },{ name:'2', shade: '2s' },{ name:'3', shade: '3s' }]" ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.shade for color in colors"></select>

<select ng-init="colors = ['one','two', 'three']" ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color for color in colors"></select>


<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color for color in ['one','two', 'three']"></select>
```

`

Happy Coding!

Comment: did you define your "ng-app" ?

Comment: you can try these codes in http://embed.plnkr.co/cB0jSd/  .... these are found as 'working'  ... 


if it still not working at your place, please build a "plnkr" for your codes and share at here, we might find the real cause.

Comment: I don't think that a plnkr will work for this problem, since the problem is probably with the configuration of my project. Can you take a look? https://github.com/Belteshazzar89/moneymap